# Is it possible to convert mex code to C++ code?

Tags: c++, mex

I have written some mex (c++) code, i have used mxArrays, and few other Matlab functions, i am wondering is it possible to convert it to C++ code easily by including the appropriate header and making some minor changes ?

edit:
By "convert", i mean that i want to compile and run my code without relying (using) on matlab.

Comment: mex is a binary format that is platform dependent. I really doubt you've written binary code.

Comment: @carlosdc, from the tag description of mex 'MEX-files are dynamically linked subroutines produced from C, C++ or Fortran source code that,...' So, assume he wrote C++.

Comment: do you have only the MEX file, or also the code used to compile it?

Comment: I converted my initial Matlab code to mex (C++) code gradually to increase its speed.

Comment: -1. Let me see if I get this right... You have your MATLAB extension in C++ and want to convert it to C++?

Comment: I want my code to compile and run independent of Matlab. I can't compile and run my current code (c++ in mex environment) without using Matlab.

Comment: *"I want my code to compile and run independent of Matlab."* Well...then all you have to do is provide your code with all the support that Matlab usually provides. Alas, that is going to be a *monster* job if you use more than the simplest Matlab features.

Comment: @dmckee, and carlosdc, That's not a bad thing to ask for. Without other information he can't know if such a library already exists. So why not ask on SO?

Comment: @JohanLundberg: my annoyance was that even when his code links to the Matlab runtime, it is still C++. So it makes no sense to want to convert that to C++. It took the OP like five rounds of questioning for him to realize that his real question was about making his code not depend/link to Matlab. Yesterday this struck me as not putting enough effort into the question. But yes, JohanLundberg, there is a real question here, and I may have downvoted prematurely, which I have undone.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, making this work depends greatly on the nature of the MATLAB functions you are using.  Since you have successfully ported much of your MATLAB code to C++, I suggest you continue doing so until you are no longer reliant on the MATLAB libraries to build.

Are there any toolbox functions you are relying on?  If so this may be a bigger task than you realize.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can make executable by using SimulinkCoder - so you can run it without Matlab ... but you still must use Matlab to make executable every time you make change in the code.

- Make basic Simulink model with single S-function block in which you specify your mex file.
- Use SimulinkCoder (Real Time Workshop) to make executable out of the Simulink model.